# Save string with color into RTF?

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, rtf

I have a Method that takes a string and converts it into rtf.
You can also set the font-type, -style and -size.
For that i am using a `RichTextBox`.
Now i have the problem that this Method also has to convert the Color of the Text into rtf.
The `RichTextBox` does have the property `.ForeColor` but the color seems not to be in the resolving rtf-string.

Currently the Method looks like this:

```
private static string ConvertToRtf(string text, 
                                   string fontFamilyName, 
                                   FontStyle fontStyle, 
                                   int fontSize) {
    System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox = 
        new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

    richTextBox.Font = new Font(new FontFamily(fontFamilyName), 
                                fontSize, 
                                fontStyle, 
                                GraphicsUnit.Point);

        richTextBox.Text = text;
        string result = richTextBox.Rtf;

        return result;
    }
```

And as mentioned i would like to Convert the Color, too.

Comment: `richTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;` worked for me.  Text came out red.

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry, that was my mistake. The method does not save the rtf, it just converts normal Text into it. And when i save the returned rtf-String the color is gone.

Comment: It's not very clear what the issue is.  What are you doing with this function?

Comment: Ok, i found the problem... The program that uses my method puts my string into a template and then the color is ignored... Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The RichTextBox has a function for that: [RichTextBox.SaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335487%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. The method does not save the rtf, it just converts normal Text into it. And when i save the returned rtf-String the color is gone.

Comment: Ok, i found the problem... The program that uses my method puts my string into a template and then the color is ignored... Sorry for that.